# Ajuda com tratamento de arquivos - Linguagem C

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, struct, data-manipulation

Estou fazendo um programa que aloca estruturas de alunos dinamicamente e cadastra as notas de diversos alunos. Até ai, tudo ok (mostra a média, maior e menor nota e o total de alunos quando encerra o programa), mas agora eu preciso fazer o tratamento de arquivos.

Só que do jeito que eu estou fazendo, eu basicamente escrevo qualquer matricula (independente se tem ou não) e dai sim grava no arquivo de texto, mas eu queria não precisar escrever novamente e sim pegar a matricula e nota que foram cadastradas no inicio do programa. E dai quando apertar a opção de ler, apenas mostrar as informações já salvas (e não cadastrar novamente).

Vou deixar o código completo, está sem erro de compilação, então se ficar mais fácil de entender, apenas rodar.

ps: É meu primeiro contato com tratamento de arquivos, tenho que estudar muito mais e aceito indicações de sites/vídeos também. Mas, como eu estou buscando faz uma semana e não consigo solucionar, gostaria de ajuda dos mais experientes =]

Obrigada desde já!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Aluno
{
    int matricula;
    int nota;
};

void cadastraMatricula(struct Aluno *alunos, int quantidadeAlunos);
float calcularMediaAlunos(struct Aluno *alunos, int quantidadeAlunos);
void encontrarMaiorEMenorNota(struct Aluno *alunos, int quantidadeAlunos, int *maiorNota_p, int *menorNota_p);
int GravaArquivo(char *arquivo, char *modo, char* texto);
void Leitura(char* arquivo, char* modo);
void BuscaLinha(char * linha);
void Gravacao(char* arquivo, char* modo);
int BuscaDados(FILE* Arq, char* linha);




int main()
{
    char* arquivo = "ArquivoTex.txt";
    char* modo = "a+";

    struct Aluno *alunos = NULL;

    int op = -1, alunosTot = 0, maiorNota = 0, menorNota = 0;


    do
    {
        printf("\nEscolha uma opcao abaixo:");
        printf("\n0 - Encerrar o Programa\n");
        printf("1 - Cadastrar Aluno\n");
        printf("2 - Ler os dados do arquivo\n");

        scanf("%d", &op);

        if (op == 1)
        {
            struct Aluno *aluno_temp_p = (struct Aluno *)realloc(
                                             alunos, (alunosTot + 1) * sizeof(struct Aluno));

            if (aluno_temp_p != NULL)
            {

                cadastraMatricula(aluno_temp_p, alunosTot);

                alunos = aluno_temp_p;
                alunosTot += 1;

            }

        }

        else if (op == 2){
             // Faz UMA gravacao de cada vez
    Gravacao(arquivo,modo);
    // Faz a leitura de TODAS as linha do arquivo
    Leitura(arquivo, modo);


        }

    }


    while (op != 0);

    printf("- Total de Alunos: %d\n", alunosTot);

    encontrarMaiorEMenorNota(alunos, alunosTot, &maiorNota, &menorNota);

    printf("- Menor Nota: %d\n", menorNota);
    printf("- Maior Nota: %d\n", maiorNota);

    printf("- Media Geral: %.2f", calcularMediaAlunos(alunos, alunosTot));
    printf("\n------------------------------\n");



}

void cadastraMatricula(struct Aluno *alunos, int quantidadeAlunos)
{
    printf("\nInforme a matricula: \n");
    scanf("%d", &alunos[quantidadeAlunos].matricula);

    printf("Informe a nota:\n");
    scanf("%d", &alunos[quantidadeAlunos].nota);
}

float calcularMediaAlunos(struct Aluno *alunos, int quantidadeAlunos)
{
    int i = 0, soma = 0;

    if (quantidadeAlunos == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < quantidadeAlunos; i++)
    {
        soma += alunos[i].nota;
    }

    return (float)soma / quantidadeAlunos;
}

void encontrarMaiorEMenorNota(struct Aluno *alunos, int quantidadeAlunos,
                              int *maiorNota_p, int *menorNota_p)
{

    int i = 0;

    if (quantidadeAlunos == 0)
    {
        *maiorNota_p = 0;
        *menorNota_p = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < quantidadeAlunos; i++)
        {

            if (alunos[i].nota > *maiorNota_p)
            {
                *maiorNota_p = alunos[i].nota;
            }

            else if (alunos[i].nota < *menorNota_p)
            {
                *menorNota_p = alunos[i].nota;
            }
        }
    }
}


void Leitura(char* arquivo, char* modo)
{
    FILE* Arq;
    int retorno=99;
    char buffer[1024];

    Arq = fopen(arquivo, modo);
    if (Arq == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo...");
        return;
    }

    printf("\n");
    while (retorno  != 0)
    {
        retorno = BuscaDados(Arq, buffer);
        if (retorno != NULL)
            printf("\n ---> %s  ", buffer);

    }

    printf("\n");
    fclose(Arq);
}



int GravaArquivo(char *arquivo, char *modo, char* texto)
{
    FILE* Arq;
    int retorno=0;

    Arq = fopen ( arquivo, modo ) ;
    if(Arq == NULL)
     {
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!");
        return (-1);
     }
    retorno = fputs(texto, Arq);
    if (retorno != 0)
    {
        printf("Erro de gravacao!");
        return (-1);
     }

    fclose(Arq);
    return 0;
}

void BuscaLinha(char * aluno)
{
    printf("\nDigite : ");
    scanf("%s",aluno);
}


void Gravacao(char* arquivo, char* modo)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    BuscaLinha(buffer);
    strcat(buffer,"\n");

    if (GravaArquivo(arquivo, modo, buffer) != 0)
    {
       printf("Erro na gravacao do arquivo!");
    }

}

int BuscaDados(FILE* Arq, char* linha)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    linha[0] = '\0';
    int resultado = 0;

    resultado = fgets(linha, sizeof(buffer), Arq);

    return resultado;

}
```

Comment: Alic, seja muito bem-vindo ao [pt.so], não use cumprimentos/saudações nas perguntas, veja [que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Obrigada! Editado por aqui hahaha

Answer (score 0):

> ps: É meu primeiro contato com tratamento de arquivos, tenho que estudar muito mais e aceito indicações de sites/vídeos também. Mas, como eu estou buscando faz uma semana e não consigo solucionar, gostaria de ajuda dos mais experientes

Tratar arquivos é bem simples em C, se comparado com tratar memória e endereços.

Há duas maneiras de fazer isso:

- uma com funções orientadas a linha e que supõe que o conteúdo estará disposto em registros de tamanho indeterminado e separados por um delimitador, a popular linha, separada por `\n` o popular `newline`

  - as funções usadas nesse caso podem ser `fscanf()`, `fprintf()`, `fgets()`, `fputs()` e outras.
- a outra maneira supõe o conteúdo disposto em blocos, que podem ser de um único byte, podendo os blocos serem tratados por unidade

  - funções nesse caso podem ser `fread()`, `fwrite()`, `fseek()`, `ftell()` e outras.

Para o C não existe tipo de arquivo e são apenas bytes. É sua decisão usar um modo ou outro. Não existe arquivo texto ou arquivo binário. Existe só arquivo. Você pode ler arquivos ditos binários como texto e vice-versa, e os resultados variam do normal ao desastre inesperado.

#### Um exemplo

O programa a seguir cria um arquivo como *binário* e lê como *texto*. É inútil. Serve só para mostrar algumas das funções e a pouca relevância da idéia de "tipo de arquivo".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* arquivo = "coisa.txt";
    FILE*       dados   = fopen(arquivo, "w");
    if (dados == NULL) return -1;

    char   bloco[]   = {"12345678123456781234567812345678"};
    size_t tam_bloco = 8;
    size_t n_blocos  = 4;
    size_t res       = fwrite(bloco, tam_bloco, n_blocos, dados);
    printf("fwrite() retornou %zd\n", res);
    if (res == n_blocos)
        printf("fwrite() gravados %zd blocos de %zd bytes\n", n_blocos,
               tam_bloco);

    char val = 0;
    res      = fwrite(&val, sizeof(val), 1, dados);
    printf("fwrite() retornou %zd\n", res);
    if (res == sizeof(val))
        printf("fwrite() gravados %zd blocos de %zd bytes\n", (size_t)1,
               (size_t)sizeof(val));

    size_t tam_arquivo = ftell(dados);
    printf("ftell() reporta %zd como tamanho do arquivo '%s'\n",
           tam_arquivo, arquivo);
    fclose(dados);

    dados = fopen(arquivo, "r");
    printf("arquivo \"%s\" reaberto\n", arquivo);
    if (dados == NULL) return -2;
    char  linha[200];
    char* ret = fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), dados);
    if (ret == NULL) return -3;
    printf("fgets() retornou ok e leu \"%s\" do arquivo\n", linha);

    printf("Tentando ler outra linha...\n");
    ret = fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), dados);
    if (ret == NULL)
    {
        printf("fgets() retornou NULL\n");
        if (feof(dados)) printf("feof() indica fim de arquivo\n");
    }
    fclose(dados);
}
```

#### saída do exemplo

```
fwrite() retornou 4
fwrite() gravados 4 blocos de 8 bytes
fwrite() retornou 1
fwrite() gravados 1 blocos de 1 bytes
ftell() reporta 33 como tamanho do arquivo 'coisa.txt'
arquivo "coisa.txt" reaberto
fgets() retornou ok e leu "12345678123456781234567812345678" do arquivo
Tentando ler outra linha...
fgets() retornou NULL
feof() indica fim de arquivo
```

#### De volta ao seu programa

```
int BuscaDados(FILE* Arq, char* linha)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    linha[0]      = '\0';
    int resultado = 0;
    resultado = fgets(linha, sizeof(buffer), Arq);

    return resultado;
}
```

Tem um problema particular aqui: `fgets()` retorna `char*` um ponteiro para `linha` no seu caso. Não retorna `int`. Veja o exemplo que te mostrei acima.

Escreva em torno dos dados

#### Seus dados

```
struct Aluno
{
    int matricula;
    int nota;
};

// ...

    struct Aluno* alunos = NULL;
```

E sua idéia é tratar `alunos` como um vetor de `struct Aluno` e usar `realloc()` a cada novo aluno para redimensionar a estrutura.
Já vi muito isso em programas de estudantes mas não é uma boa idéia. É frágil e muito pouco eficiente.

Eis o que acontece: a cada `realloc()` o sistema tenta encontrar uma área com capacidade para conter o novo tamanho, e possivelmente copia o que já tem para a nova área. Não há nenhuma garantia de que vai aumentar mas continuar no mesmo lugar. E essas cópias podem demorar. E são dispensáveis. Mais ainda: uma área vai ser liberada e outra vai ser criada. Depois os dados serão copiados e o ponteiro reatribuído para o novo endereço. Se algo falhar no caminho dependendo da implementação se pode perder os dois endereços e todos os dados. Então primeiro se chama `realloc()` com um ponteiro temporário e se deu certo aí então se copia o endereço para o ponteiro original. Você fez assim com `aluno_temp_p`.

Mas o comum é se alocar uma quantidade maior de registros a cada vez, como 10 ou 100 alunos. E conforme for usando vai alocando mais blocos iguais. Sem cópias constantes, menos riscos. Mais rápido. Só realoca quando esgota, e usando um bloco razoável fica mais simples.

#### as funções

```c
void  cadastraMatricula(struct Aluno* alunos, int quantidadeAlunos);
float calcularMediaAlunos(struct Aluno* alunos, int quantidadeAlunos);
void  encontrarMaiorEMenorNota(struct Aluno* alunos,
                               int quantidadeAlunos, int* maiorNota_p,
                               int* menorNota_p);
int   GravaArquivo(char* arquivo, char* modo, char* texto);
void  Leitura(char* arquivo, char* modo);
void  BuscaLinha(char* linha);
void  Gravacao(char* arquivo, char* modo);
int   BuscaDados(FILE* Arq, char* linha);
```

Repare que tem que ficar controlando à parte a quantidade de alunos e passando para as funções e tudo fica complicado: imagine se tive 4 turmas de alunos para controlar no programa

#### Um nível a mais de composição

```
typedef struct
{
    int matricula;
    int nota;

} Aluno;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned qtd;         // quantos tem agora
    unsigned bloco;       // alocados bloco a bloco
    unsigned capacidade;  // quantos tem agora alocados
    Aluno*   al;          // o vetor

} Alunos;

void  cadastraMatricula(Alunos* alunos);
float calcularMediaAlunos(Alunos* alunos);
void  encontrarMaiorEMenorNota(
    Alunos* alunos, int* maiorNota_p, int* menorNota_p);

int  GravaArquivo(char* arquivo, char* modo, char* texto);
void Leitura(char* arquivo, char* modo);
void BuscaLinha(char* linha);
void Gravacao(char* arquivo, char* modo);
int  BuscaDados(FILE* Arq, char* linha);
```

Entenda que se usar assim fica tudo mais fácil: `Alunos` é o seu conjunto de dados. Dentro de cada `Alunos` tem a quantia, e pode definir lá a alocação dos caras, em blocos, se preferir. Essa é a noção de encapsulamento.

Mais ainda, se suspeita que vai precisar muitas vezes da maior e menor nota e da média pode deixar isso na própria estrutura, economizando um tempo e muitos loops em troca de uns poucos `int`:

```
    unsigned soma; // para calcular a media
    int      maior; // maior e menor nota
    int      menor;
```

#### Sobre os arquivos

Para o seu uso é mais simples gravar e ler os registros do disco em termos da estrutura de `Aluno` no início e no final da execução, e durante o uso do programa usar tudo na memória. É só um exercício afinal. E para agilizar as coisas acho que um simples vetor de índice para as matrículas pode ser a solução: manter atualizado um vetor com as matrículas e a posição do aluno no vetor e assim você não precisa inserir na ordem ;)

O índice pode ficar dentro da estrutura ou em uma estrutura a parte no programa, é só um vetor de `int` afinal. Como não serão milhões de registros isso dá uma performance boa com bom uso do cache e sem o stress de manter em ordem... Pesquisar no vetor é quase instantâneo.

Não vou escrever um programa todo agora, mas para ter um exemplo de como seria, considere

### Exemplo

Este programa declara e usa umas turmas, de uma maneira comum de se manter esse tipo de estrutura. Se resolver seguir por um caminho assim e tiver dificuldade posso implementar o resto

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "alunos.h"

int main(void)
{
    Alunos* turma_1 = cria_turma(30); // blocos de 30 
    Alunos classe[10]; // 10 grupos de alunos
    printf("Turma 1 tem %d alunos\n", turma_1->qtd);
    turma_1 = apaga_turma(turma_1);
    return 0;
}
```

Repare que fica fácil por exemplo ter um vetor de turmas de alunos, o que seria quase impensável usando apenas um vetor de aluno para cada turma, e os contadores separados.

#### saída do exemplo

```
Turma 1 tem 0 alunos
```

- apaga_turma()` retorna um ponteiro assim se pode usar para invalidar o ponteiro da turma apagada, na mesma linha e na mesma hora.

#### criando e apagando uma turma

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "alunos.h"

Alunos* apaga_turma(Alunos* T)
{
    free(T->index);  // apaga o indice
    free(T->al);     // os alunos
    free(T);         // e apaga a estrutura
    return NULL;
}

Alunos* cria_turma(unsigned N)
{
    Alunos* novo = (Alunos*) malloc(sizeof(Alunos));
    if ( novo == NULL ) return NULL;

    novo->qtd= 0;
    novo->bloco = N;
    novo->capacidade = N;

    novo->soma = 0;
    novo->maior = INT_MIN;
    novo->menor = INT_MAX;

    novo->al = (Aluno*) malloc(N * sizeof(Aluno));
    novo->index = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    
    return novo;
}
```

Com tudo localizado DENTRO das funções fica mais fácil de controlar.

Note que a turma já começa vazia, mas o primeiro bloco de ponteiros é já criado, e o vetor de índices.

Só um palpite.